# How to inject a generic type

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have a repository interface that receives a generic type.

```
interface AuthRepo<R> {
    val isUserAuthenticatedInFirebase: Boolean
    suspend fun oneTapSignInWithGoogle(): R
    suspend fun firebaseSignInWithGoogle(): R
}
```

The generic type is the class is `BeginSignInResult` that returns the result of the login. This class is not owned by me, so I have to inject it with a module. Here it is.

```
@Singleton
class AuthRepoImpl @Inject constructor(
   ...
   @Named(SING_IN_RESULT)
   private val singInResult: BeginSignInResult,
   @Named(SING_UP_RESULT)
   private val singUpResult: BeginSignInResult,
   ...
) : AuthRepo<BeginSignInResult>
```

This is the module where I am injecting the repository implementation.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class AuthModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun provideAuthRepository(
        authRepoImpl: AuthRepoImpl
    ): AuthRepo<BeginSignInResult>
}
```

## The problem

As this class is not my property, I have to inject it with a module. This `BeginSignInResult` class also needs other classes that are also injected with modules. This is the code that injects it.

```
    @Provides
    @Named(AuthConstant.SING_IN_RESULT)
    suspend fun provideSingInResult(
        oneTapClient: SignInClient,
        @Named(AuthConstant.SIGN_IN_REQUEST)
        signUpRequest: BeginSignInRequest
    ) : BeginSignInResult {
        return oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signUpRequest).await()
    }

    @Provides
    @Named(AuthConstant.SING_UP_RESULT)
    suspend fun provideSingUpResult(...) : BeginSignInResult ...
```

## Hilt Error

This is the compile error. I think the use case that accesses the repository does not need to be shown

```
com...AuthRepo<com...BeginSignInResult> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
com...AuthRepo<com..BeginSignInResult> is injected at
com...OneTapSingInUseCase(authRepo)
com...OneTapSingInUseCase<com...BeginSignInResult> is injected at
com...AuthRepo<com....BeginSignInResult> is injected at
com...OneTapSingInUseCase(authRepo)
com...OneTapSingInUseCase<com...BeginSignInResult> is injected at
com...LoginViewModel(�, oneTapUseCase)
com...LoginViewModel is injected at
com...LoginViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
@dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com....App_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com...App_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com...App_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```